# How to recover Bacula when you run out of space in volumes?

Tags: backup, bacula

I accidentally started backing up much more than was expected so I filled all volumes. I now fixed the issue of what is being backed up and what isn't; but how do I get backing up again?

I cannot create more volumes and I'd rather not destroy volumes. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up destroying volumes, not everything but the oldest ones. One by one leaving space for the new backups. I've run out of space and had to re-do this several times. Painful, boring and slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to simply start from scratch. I know this isn't what you want to hear, but the alternatives are very convoluted and may leave you with backup volumes that can't be used anyway.